# Assigning a name from an array list to a group

Tags: java

Hi guys this is really stumping me, I need to assign the names from the array list to the group a or b, my question is if I can just randomly select the names rather than randomly selecting group A or B

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GroupPicker{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("GroupPicker1.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            names.add(input.next());
            String group = "";
            String getgroup = assignGroup(group);
            for (String n: names) {
                System.out.println(n + " is assinged to " + getgroup);
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "\n" + "project groups: ");
        System.out.println("Group A: ");
        System.out.println("Group B: ");
    }

    public static String assignGroup(String group) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int groupnumber;
        groupnumber = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;

        switch(groupnumber) {
            case 1:
                group = "group B";
                break;
            case 2:
                group = "group A";
        }

        return group;
    }

}
```

Comment: Once you have loaded all the names into the list, you could then shuffle the arraylist, then finally just alternate adding everyone from the list to group A or B. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200129/sort-arraylist-in-random-order

Comment: That probably depends on your requirements but in theory you could do it either way. If you assign names to random groups you may get differently sized groups, if you pick random names for each group you'd either have to alternate between the groups or at least know how many names to pick at max. This would lead to a more uniform distribution of names.

Comment: Your code, however, is flawed (and not properly formatted): in your while loop you add the next name to the list, then get the random group and then ... you add _all_ the names that are currently in the `names` list to that group. Instead you probably just want to do the following: `String nextName = input.next(); names.add(nextName); assignToGroup(nextName);` - Another side note: that parameter to `assignGroup()` isn't used at all and thus could be removed or could be the name that is assigned. In that case print "name is assigned to group" inside that method.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the loading of the names in a separate method:

```
private static List<String> loadNames() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("GroupPicker1.txt"));

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        names.add(input.next());
    }

    return names;
}
```

- Create 2 lists, one for each group.
- Then go through the names list and randomly assign each of them to a list;

(If you have only 2 groups, then you can use `rand.nextBoolean()`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    List<String> names = loadNames();

    ArrayList<String> groupA = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> groupB = new ArrayList<>();

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (String n: names) {
        if (rand.nextBoolean()) {
            System.out.println(n + " is assigned to group A");
            groupA.add(n);
        } else {
            System.out.println(n + " is assigned to group B");
            groupB.add(n);
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("project groups: ");
    System.out.println("Group A: " + groupA);
    System.out.println("Group B: " + groupB);
}
```

There are ways to make it lot nicer using Streams if you want

**EDIT: A Stream version**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Random rand = new Random();

    Map<Boolean, List<String>> groups = Files.lines(Paths.get("GroupPicker1.txt"))
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> rand.nextBoolean()));

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("project groups: ");
    System.out.println("Group A: " + groups.get(true));
    System.out.println("Group B: " + groups.get(false));
}
```